# Database design: cache similar interests between users or dynamic calculation with each query

Tags: database, database-design

I have a primary user table and a secondary 1-M table that stores user interests.

One of the main queries users make is querying other users with similar interests (this is done quite frequently). Since I know that the user interests are updated much less frequently than the selection queries and sometimes only ran via a subset (not against the full user database), I would like to run a query with every update that populates a relationship table between other users and run the selection queries off this table.

My question is two-fold:

1. Is this a good practice in general or is dynamic calculation with each fetch recommended instead?
2. In the interest of normalization, should I simply store the number of similar interests and run queries to fetch the individual details when required?

Thanks!